# Visual Studio 2008: make Ctrl + K, Ctrl + N (next bookmark) stay within the same file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2003 you could jump to the next bookmark with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>; it stayed within the same file and wrapped around to the top of the file when there were no furter bookmarks in the file. Now in VS 2008 this seems to have changed, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> jumps to other files with bookmarks. How can I change this back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, you have two other commands that by default are not assigned a shortcut:

- Previous Bookmark In Document
- Next Bookmark In Document

You'll see them if you go to the Edit->Bookmarks menu. You can bind them to a shortcut if you go to **Options->Preferences->Environment->Keyboard** and look them up as `Edit.PreviousBookmarkInDocument` and `Edit.NextBookmarkInDocument`.

Cheers!